# Problems with Universal Generalization

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I’ve been studying universal generalization recently and, according to the textbooks, $\forall x Q(x)$ can be derived from $Q(a)$, if the variable $a$ is arbitrary. A variable is arbitrary, when it does not appear in any of the undischarged assumptions throughout the derivation.

**Example $1$:** Prove that $\forall x Q(x)$ derives from $\forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]$ and $\forall x P(x)$.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
1. & \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)] & \\
2. & \forall x P(x) & \\ \hline
3. & P(a) \implies Q(a) & (1.; \text{U.I.}) \\
4. & P(a) & (2.; \text{U.I.}) \\
5. & Q(a) & (3.,4.;\text{M.P.})\\
6. & \forall xQ(x) & (5.; \text{U.G.})
\end{array}$$

We could generalize $Q(a)$ in step $6$, because the variable $a$ was not in the premises of our proof (steps $1$ and $2$).

However, consider the following example:

**Example $2$:** Prove that $\forall x Q(x)$ derives from $\forall x [P(a) \rightarrow Q(x)]$ and $P(a)$.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
1. & \forall x[P(a) \implies Q(x)] & \\
2. & P(a) & \\ \hline
3. & P(a) \implies Q(a) & (1.; \text{U.I.}) \\
4. & Q(a) & (2.,3.; \text{M.P.}) \\
5. & \forall xQ(x) & (4.; \text{U.G.}) \\ & & \text{MISTAKE: $a$ appears in $P(a)$}
\end{array}$$

In this case, according to the definition of arbitrariness presented above, we are actually not able to universally generalize $Q(a)$ in step $5$, since the variable $a$ does appear in one of the premises (step $2$). Nevertheless, $\forall x Q(x)$ does derive from $\forall x [P(a) \rightarrow Q(x)]$ and $P(a)$, so universal generalization should be possible here. Where is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: Is there nothing about that element $a$ in the example 2? I mean, does the text say that $a$ is arbitrary or not?

Comment: I think that maybe you shoudn’t use the same letter $a$ in the step 3. Because the $a$ in $Q(a)$ should be arbitrary, right?

Comment: Yes.  Rather the term put into $Q(\raise{1ex}\downarrow)$ should be arbitrary *since you want to generalise*.  A predicate *is* an undischarged assumption, so you cannot use $a$ for this term.  Thus you need to introduce a *fresh* term, such as $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that $(\forall x)Q(x)$ derives from $(\forall x)[P(a) \implies Q(x)]$ and $P(a)$.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
1. & \forall x[P(a) \implies Q(x)] & \\
2. & P(a) & \\ \hline
3. & P(a) \implies Q(x_0) & (1.; \text{U.I.}) \\
4. & Q(x_0) & (2.,3.; \text{M.P.}) \\
5. & \forall xQ(x) & (4.; \text{U.G.})
\end{array}$$

Note that, when we use the U.I. rule, we are considering that $P(a) \implies Q(x_0)$, for **any** chosen $x_0$. So, in the end, you have $Q(x_0)$ for **all** $x_0$. Then, we only have to use the U.G. rule. $\square$

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer, Mr Air Mike. It is somewhat curious, however, that the definition of arbitrariness does not mean exactly "any variable" nor "no assumption using a free variable", rather a variable that is not free in the premises.